# How can I place my icons and heading in one line

Tags: html, css

I don't know why but I used a heading `<h1>` and then some icons using font-awesome `<i>` . For some reason they do not display next to each other in one line.

The heading is in one line and the icons are below the heading.

**This is the code i am using**

```
   <div id="footer">
            <h1>foot</h1>
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
   </div>


#footer {
   clear:both;
   max-height:200px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: yellow;

}
#footer i {
   margin: 10px;
   font-size: 30px;}
```

Comment: `#footer{display:flex}`

Comment: Because `h*` tag will fill in the while line by default... Try `display: inline-block` on the h1.

Comment: Adriana6 answered the question, but an `h1` tag in a footer isn't semantically correct, and the parent should usually use the actual `<footer>` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp) for even further semantic compliance, also don't need the `clear:both` since you're not floating anything, just a quick note.

Answer (score 0):

`foot` showed on one line because the default style contains `display: block`.
Update that attribute to `display: inline-block` and you can see all items of footer in one line.

```css
#footer {
clear:both;
max-height:200px;
width: 100%;
background-color: yellow;

}
#footer h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#footer i {
margin: 10px;
font-size: 30px;}
```

```html
 <div id="footer">
            <h1>foot</h1>
            <i class="fab fa-facebook">a</i>
            <i class="fab fa-instagram">b</i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter">c</i>
            <i class="fab fa-youtube">d</i>
        </div>
```